# Discount Rule [Magento ]

Tags: php, magento

MAGENTO, i'm using 1.7 community edition,

I want to create a discount rule:

Lets say,
Product A costs USD 100.

if some one buys more than 1 product A (i.e QUANTITY > 1),
then the rest of the Product A should cost USD 50 (50% discount).

example,
3 items in the cart
product A (1) = USD 100
product A (2) = USD 50     [50% discount]
product A (3) = USD 50     [50% discount]

TOTAL = Rs 200

thanks in advance,